# How to speedup tensorflow compile time?

Tags: tensorflow, compiler-optimization

I am doing some customization to the tensorflow core, so I am compiling it several times. Currently, my problem is that each compilation takes about 25 minutes and I would like to reduce the compile time.
Each time, I compile using the instruction at this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources)
on a machine equipped with a Intel i7 and 12gb of RAM.

Executing the linux command htop, I notice that my CPUs are running almost at 100% for all the time, while the RAM seems to be sufficient (it uses about 8GB).

Is there any way to achieve a speedup in the compile time, both acting in terms of hardware (maybe a SSD could help?) and software (e.g., by setting some compile options?) ?

Comment: Have you tried to disable XLA?

Comment: Are you using [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org/)?

Comment: @Patwie XLA is disabled

Comment: @janbernlöhr Currently, I'm not using it. Can it reduce the compile time? If yes, is there any tutorial about how to compile tensorflow using ccache?

Comment: @Dan Yes it can definetly help by avoiding recompilation of unchanged files. You can find a manual on how to setup ccache here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/470545/how-do-i-set-up-ccache Afterwards you need to run `./configure` again so that bazel picks up the ccache wrapped verison of gcc. Then run the build as usual while watching the output of `ccache -s` to show that there are actual cache hits.

Answer (score 0):

SSD will increase the speed of compiling too. And you can use bazel option is --jobs to define number of jobs to work at the same time.